# PHP not dividing correctly

Tags: php

I have some PHP code that is dividing two numbers that are pulled from a mySQL database however it is not computing correctly. When I echo $comm and `$total_fix` individually, the numbers are correct. However, when I echo the division of the two it is not the correct answer. Both numbers are `DECIMAL(10,0)` data type in the database. Below is the PHP code

```
$percent_comm = $comm / $total_fix;
$percent_comm = number_format($percent_comm, 2, '.', ',');                     
echo "<td align=\"center\">".$percent_comm."</td>";
```

here `$comm = 2700`, `$total_fix = 75` but `$percent_comm` is computing to be `0.03` when it should be `36`

Comment: What if you echo without formatting the numbers with `number_format()` ?

Comment: There's no problem in your code. The input values are likely wrong. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/vPs8wn

Comment: If you want something in per cent, you should multiply it by 100.

Comment: The `cent` of `percent` means `100`.... where are you factoring that into your division?

Comment: Are you sure the input values aren't backwards? 75/2700 would equal 0.03 when rounded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: I can't reproduce http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/68n-bsy

Comment: I'm almost certain that you are very confused about what a percentage is and some other basic mathematical operations. The code you pasted computes 36 but what kind of twisted relationship is required between the numbers 2700 and 75 to call it 36 percent is beyond me...

Comment: If I echo without formatting I still get an incorrect result. The values aren't backwards. If I take it to 4 decimals its .0267. 75/2700 would be .0278. When I echo $comm it's 2700 and echo $total_fix it's 75 so I don't understand how the inputs could change in the equation to produce an incorrect result. $percent_comm is just the name of the variable. I will turn it into a percentage once I get the equation to produce a correct result.

Comment: Debug your values before and after the operation. Also, use parenthesis just in case.

Comment: 2700 / 75 = 36, your check was backwards from what your code computes. But to get a percentage, multiply by 100 the result of dividing: `(75.0 / 2700) * 100` = 2.7 percent.

Comment: I think I found the issue but not sure how to fix it. I changed the operator to + so it would be easier to see the result. $comm + $total_fix is computing 77 (i.e. 2,700 + 75 = 77). It looks like it's only considering the first digit from 2,700 in the equation. I have confimed this with other examples from the database. Anyone know how I fix this? $comm is being pulled from a mySQL database using SELECT FORMAT(SUM(Commission),0)..... and again the Commission column is of DECIMAL(10,0) type.

Comment: I solved this by changing the mySQL command to just SELECT SUM(Commission) and then formatting $comm using PHP's number_format and now the equation produces the correct result. Thank you everyone for your help.  (I would post this in the answer section but I would have to wait 8 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see on your comments, you are getting the $comm variable as a string with a comma, because of the format. I suggest to convert the formatted string into a valid number.

Mean while I'll recomend this:

```
 $comm = '2,700';
 $comm = str_replace(',','',$comm);
```

That remove the comma from your number.

Comment: You are welcome @Steve. I've been searching another way to do this. But, apparently this is the cleanest one. Also, if this worked for you don't forget to mark this answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the variable names, you want to know `$comm` as a percentage of `$total_fix`. Your code *almost* does this: You correctly divide `$comm/$total_fix`, and it correctly gives you `0.027`. But you got it backwards when you checked by hand: 36 is the result of dividing `2700/75` (i.e., `$total_fix/$comm`)

But to get a percentage, multiply by 100 the result of the division:

```
(75.0 / 2700) * 100 = 2.7 percent.
```

*That's* what your code should be getting.